# Changing selection color using QTextCharFormat

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtextedit

I am writing simple editor, I use QTextEdit for text edit QSyntaxHighlighter to do syntax colouring. 
Style is aplied by QTextCharFormat.

I know how to create simple styles like:

```
keyword_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
keyword_format.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkMagenta)
keyword_format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)

exception_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
exception_format.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkBlue)
exception_format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Italic)
```

but how can I change color when text is selected and:

1. selected text may contain many differently formatted tokens
2. I might want set selection background color and font color for each formatter independently

I don't know if I explained it enough clearly e.g. I have code

```
 if foobar:
     return foobar:
 else:
     raise Exception('foobar not set')
```

Now, `if`, `else`, `return` and `raise` are keywords and are formatted using `keyword_format`, `Exception` is formatted using `exception_format`. If I select text `raise Exception('foobar not set')` I would like to change `raise` keyword, say to green, `Exception` to pink and leave rest of selection as it is.

Comment: I've been trying to do something similar, i.e. swap foreground and background colors. I think pretty much the only way is to examine/modify the `QTextFragment`s in the selection. You'd have to manually decide which fragments were in the selection as well as handle splitting the start/end fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mergeCharFormat()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#mergeCharFormat) in conjunction with a QTextCursor pointing at the document() inside the QTextEdit

Usage (C++):

```cpp
QTextCursor cursor(qTextEditWidget->document());

QTextCharFormat backgrounder;
backgrounder.setBackground(Qt::black);
QTextCharFormat foregrounder;
foregrounder.setForeground(Qt::yellow);

// Apply the background
cursor.setPosition(start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor.setCharFormat(backgrounder);

cursor.setPosition(start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);

// Merge the Foreground without overwriting the background
cursor.mergeCharFormat(foregrounder);
```

It seems to work even if the cursor was moved before merging the second QTextCharFormat

Comment: I had this problem with `QGraphicsTextItem` and it seemed to still render its own selection on top of the custom cursor. The solution was to clear the selection before and after setting the custom cursor like this. However, I didn't find it needed to have separate background and foreground cursors. That didn't change anything compared to a single cursor with background and foreground set.